# Python programming: Error in reading SAS data into python

Tags: python, pandas, sas

When I tried to read a sas7bdat file in python using pandas. It shows outflow error as below. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sas('D:/My Documents/data.sas7bdat')
```

Error message:

```
OverflowError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()   
pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.cast_from_unit()

OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e9567d888396> in <module>()
----> 1 mdldata1=pd.read_sas('H:/My Documents/data.sas7bdat')
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sas\sasreader.py in read_sas(filepath_or_buffer, format, index, encoding, chunksize, iterator)
     66         return reader
     67 
---> 68     data = reader.read()
     69     reader.close()
     70     return data
...
pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()

OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1609887547.0 with the unit 'd'
```

Comment: I guess it is because the date variables are saved as mmddyy8. or mmddyy10. in sasdata file. But not sure how to fix it.

Comment: That looks like a datetime variable, not a date. Should the value be January 5, 2011 22:59:07?

Comment: If you have access to SAS, you can run `proc export outfile='$SAVEPLACE' data=$DATANAME dbms=csv; run;` to export the data to CSV, which Python will be happier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your SAS dataset might have the wrong type of format attached to the variable and it is confusing the Python routine.  Note that SAS stores dates as number of days and datetime as number of seconds.  Just changing the display format attached to a variable does not change the value of the variable.

If you can fix your SAS dataset to either use the DATETIME format so that read_sas() doesn't try to convert it to a date value.  Or use the DATEPART() function to convert the value to a valid date.

If you cannot then see if the read_sas method has an option to ignore the format attached to the varaible and just return the number of seconds as the floating point value that it is.  You can then write your own code to convert it to a date if you want.